# How to clean sticky brake dust from carbon fiber fork?

Tags: carbon, cleaning

After having wiped by Specialized Langster 2017 carbon fiber fork with a water soaked cloth, there's still some sticky brake dust left. How do I remove that without harming the carbon fiber or the matte paint?

Can I use benzine (rensebenzin in Danish)?

[image: Sticky brake dust on carbon fiber fork after wiping with water soaked cloth]

Answer (score 2):

These are what I've used in the past to clean oil grease and brake dust from my Argon 18 Matt finished frame.  [image: baby wipes] using any sort of polish will eventually make your bike shiny. Find this a quick and easy way to keep my bike clean

Comment: Interesting - I'll try that.

Comment: You want the ones that have a little detergent in them and no alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Benzine or other harsh, volatile chemicals. You could try a mixture of water and a mild dish soap or even better invest in a product that is intended to clean carbon fiber if available in your area.

One that i am familiar with is CarbonPro, i have used their products and known others that have and they seem to work well and are supposed to provide extended UV protection as well as clean and polish. I don't work for them or anything, just the only one i am familiar with.

There website can be found [here](http://www.carbonpro-sports.com/products/products-description/)

[image]

Comment: I would avoid product recommendations in an answer if you can.  Rather if possible the general properties (e.g., chemistry) that makes it appropriate for the carbon fork.